Issue in opacity animation
I am trying to build an animation where three dots display a loader.
Please refer the Code pen link : codepen
@keyframes dot-elastic-1 {
  0%, 33.33%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  16.67% {
    transform: scale(1, 1.5);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 70%;
  }
  66.67% {
    opacity: 30%;
  }
}

Right now, the elongation is working sequentially, but I am not able to ensure their opacity as the animation changes. How can we achieve that?






Your keyframes are rather odd, e.g. in dot-elastic-1, at 33.33% you have opacity as both 100% and 70% in different blocks. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

So you want to animate three dots that scale in and out sequentially, while simultaneously animating their opacity as they go. If a dot is scaling up, that also mean it's becoming fully opaque: Simply swap between the 30% ( base state ) and 70% transparency for other two dots when needed.


.dot {

width: 10px;

height: 10px;

background-color: #333;

border-radius: 50%;

display: inline-block;

animation: dot-elastic 1.5s infinite, ease-in-out;

}

.dot:nth-child(2) {

animation-delay: 0.15s;

}

.dot:nth-child(3) {

animation-delay: 0.3s;

}

@keyframes dot-elastic {

0%, 100% {

transform: scale(1);

opacity: 30%;

}

16.67% {

transform: scale(1.5);

opacity: 100%;

}

33.33% {

transform: scale(1);

opacity: 70%;

}

}
<span class="dl">
  <span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
</span>



